# Rspec shared_examples_for skips test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I use shared_examples_for as shown below, my test, "makes an auth call" gets skipped. Why is this? If I comment out the shared_examples line then my assertion fails despite it being called in let!. I verified with pry that the function call is taking place. Can someone please explain why I'm seeing these behaviors and how to fix it. Thanks!

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require "rails_helper"

describe MyFunc::Auth do
  describe ".get_value" do
    before do
      allow(JWT).to receive(:decode).and_return("myDecodedValue") 
    end

    shared_examples_for "authentication" do
      context "success" do
        let!(:stub_request) { stub_token(status: 200) }

        it "makes an auth call" do
          caller
            expect(stub_request).to have_been_requested
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I have not put shared_examples_for inside a describe before, I am following https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples.
Could you try put your shared_examples_for outside of your describe MyFunc::Auth?

Answer (score 1):

You're only defining the shared example, after this you need to actually call it by

```
include_examples "authentication"
# or
it_behaves_like "authentication"
```

You can read about the difference in [the docs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples).